# Apache, Tomcat & SSL: ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'am having troubles configuring Apache, Tomcat and SSL, this is the scenario:

I have an Apache Web Server, running and working normally (but , I can access to this one just typing:

```
https://example.com
```

Also, in this host, I have a Tomcat running and working fine in port 8080 (HTTP); I've created a mini web-app which files are inside "test" directory, I can access typing:

```
http://example.com:8080/test
```

(I know that Apache is running in 80 port and Tomcat in 8080)

What I want to do is that througt Apache an user can access to 'test' (running on Tomcat) using HTTPS, I mean:

```
https://example.com/test
```

But when I access this link appers this:

[image: Page not found]

When I access using HTTP `http://example/test` works, but I need that be HTTPS.

I also create a file config in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`, this is the content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test
</VirtualHost>
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP of website.

When I access the website `https://example.com/` (with HTTPS) I got this issue (I use the web-app in the website):

[image: Security Overview]

I use certificate Let's Encrypt (in the photo above).

I'm working with Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) and Tomcat 8.5.29

Has anyone knows why or how solve this? Thanks in advance guys.

***Log files:***

**access_log**

```
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:29 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 301 245 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:51 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.30 (internal dummy connection)"
```

**error_log** - empty

**ssl_access_log**

```
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:29 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 206
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:29 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 206
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] "-" 408 -
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] "-" 408 -
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] "-" 408 -
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - - [01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] "-" 408 -
```

**ssl_request_log**

```
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:29 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 206
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:29 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 206
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "-" -
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "-" -
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "-" -
[01/Jul/2018:06:42:49 +0000] yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "-" -
```

**ssl_error_log** - empty

yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy = IP of my machine

Comment: there are three issues with the code which I have answered below.Have a look over them.

Comment: Add `ServerAlias example.com` to both Virtual Host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 problem with the code

**First:** Problem with the **port**.Https works on `port 443` and http on `port 80`

```
 <VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
    ###Remove this redirection line to move it in separate virtual host listening to port 80
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test 
 </VirtualHost>
```

**Second:** Not having `SSLProxyEngine on` so that **proxy pass** and **proxy reverse pass** works for https connection.

**Third:** Remove the redirection rule of https from this virtual host to a new one.You need to create a **new virtual host for port 80** in which there should be a redirect rule in which all http connections redirect to https permanently.

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

**Fourth:** Also add below to all virtual host

```
ServerName example.com 
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the answer. However it worked partially, I changed the file: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` as you commented (I updated it in my question) I solved the HTTPS problem on page: `https://example.com/` but the site `https://example.com/test` continues with the 'Not Found'

Comment: Did you removed the redirect permanent line from 443 port virtual host?

Comment: Yes, I did. See my `vhost.conf` on my question, maybe help you.

Comment: From the access log of Apache you can identify from where "not found" is coming.Is it from the tomcat or Apache?Also check error.log too

Answer (score 1):

The result file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/test
</VirtualHost>
```